# CS 1.6 error with sxe Injected

Tags: technical-issues, counter-strike

i am unable to play cs 1.6 with sxeInjected 11. Upon launching game it creates log file in cs installation folder with name `sXe Injected.txt` containing following text

```
2010/09/03 18:27:15 -  
2010/09/03 18:27:15 - ------------------
2010/09/03 18:27:15 - sXe-I dll starting
2010/09/03 18:27:15 - version: 11.0 (Fix 3)
2010/09/03 18:27:16 - x86 platform detected
2010/09/03 18:27:16 -    **** Driver Initialization
2010/09/03 18:27:16 -    **** Open success
2010/09/03 18:27:16 -    **** OGL started
2010/09/03 18:27:16 -    **** Link ready
2010/09/03 18:27:16 -    **** Image ready
2010/09/03 18:27:16 - Code altered, difference found
2010/09/03 18:27:16 - (ERROR) Image error
```

Game never starts if sxeInjected is open other wise it is working fine.

Comment: This is a technical support question. While you are free to ask here, the sXe Injected forums might be a better place to ask.

Comment: stackoverflow is pretty responsive, so I though I might get answer from here

Comment: It isn't a question of responsivity. There's a very big chance only people from sXe will be able to help.

Comment: I got it fixed, see http://processorcores.blogspot.com/2009/01/sxe-injected-error-fixed.html

Answer (score 2):

I followed this blog here http://processorcores.blogspot.com/2009/01/sxe-injected-error-fixed.html. I already had CS1.6 installed therefore I skipped step 5.

Comment: Whilst this may answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to quote the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is too old now, but here's what I found.

For me, when CS 1.6 crashes, SXE will produce a log file inside of its main folder, the file is named `injected.txt` and there is a line saying this:

> Unknown module found [nvwgf2um.dll]

Then I searched for "nvwgf2um" using the Everything app on PC and it was in this location in my case:

```
C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nv_dispig.inf_amd64_c0e159863e7afdde
```

Then I deleted the `nvwgf2um.dll` file and it fixed it. (Update: I don't remember that well, but it was either `nvwgf2um.dll` or `nvlddmkm.dll`, so test both if deleting one of them didn't work)

This file is made by the graphic driver, whenever you install a new driver, you have to do these steps again.

**Update**

The "nvwgf2um" doesn't seem to be a problem anymore, instead, what caused my CS 1.6 to crash and not load (with SXE running) was that I had VT-x enabled on my PC! VT-x is used for running virtual machines, but strangely it interferes with SXE! So disabling that, fixed my issue.

To disable it with CMD (Must run as Admin):

```
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto
bcdedit /set nx AlwaysOff
shutdown /s
```

And if you need VT-x for working with Virtual Machines, then enable it via:

```
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off
bcdedit /set nx AlwaysOn
shutdown /s
```

(Virtual machines work without VT-x as well, but I found that enabling VT-x greatly improves the speed of virtual machines.)

To see if your VT-x is enabled or not, use [this](https://leomoon.com/downloads/desktop-apps/leomoon-cpu-v/) app:

If it's enabled, there's a check mark on the right, if it's not, there's a X mark:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to install the CS1.6 again and if it doesn't work go to [counter-strike.net](http://counter-strike.net) for FAQ's. Or get another setup for reinstallation if possible.